# Angular CLI doesn't render html

Tags: node.js, angular-cli, mean-stack

Few days ago everything worked, then I created few more routes and since that moment Angular stopped rendering templates. There is no errors, it navigates URL in browser but no template..

Here is the routing module:

```js
const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: BlogListComponent },
  { path: ':id', component: BlogDetailComponent },
  { path: 'new', component: BlogAddComponent },
  { path: ':id/edit', component: BlogEditComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class RoutingModule { }
```

App module:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    BlogDetailComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    BlogListComponent,
    BlogAddComponent,
    BlogEditComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RoutingModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule

  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers: [RouterModule, AuthService, PostService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I believe there is problem with forms. I tried to change `this.formBuilder.group` to `new FormGroup` but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Do you see any error messages in the Console tab in Developer Tools?

Comment: No, there is just "Angular is running ..." or whatever..

Comment: Yes, sure, angular cli doesn't _render_ anything. What is the command you use ? Maybe there is no template to render at all.